# Yocto Qt6 build - run QML app on xcb or eglfs

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi, yocto

finally I was able to bitbake a yocto Qt6 image for raspberry pi 3. I can now run my QML app if I run it with -platform linuxfb

If I try -platform xcb, I get this error:

```
qt.qpa.plugin: From 6.5.0, xcb-cursor0 or libxcb-cursor0 is needed to load the Qt xcb platform plugin.
```

How do I add these libraries to my image?

If I try -platform eglfs, I get this error with QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1:

```
qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: checking directory path "/usr/lib/plugins/platforms" ...
qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: looking at "/usr/lib/plugins/platforms/libqvkkhrdisplay.so"
qt.core.plugin.loader: Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/plugins/platforms/libqvkkhrdisplay.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "vkkhrdisplay"
        ]
    },
    "archlevel": 0,
    "className": "QVkKhrDisplayIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 394496
}


qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: Got keys from plugin meta data QList("vkkhrdisplay")
qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: looking at "/usr/lib/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so"
qt.core.plugin.loader: Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "eglfs"
        ]
    },
    "archlevel": 0,
    "className": "QEglFSIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 394496
}


qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: Got keys from plugin meta data QList("eglfs")
qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: looking at "/usr/lib/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so"
qt.core.plugin.loader: Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "vnc"
        ]
    },
    "archlevel": 0,
    "className": "QVncIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 394496
}


qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: Got keys from plugin meta data QList("vnc")
qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: looking at "/usr/lib/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
qt.core.plugin.loader: Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "xcb"
        ]
    },
    "archlevel": 0,
    "className": "QXcbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 394496
}


qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: Got keys from plugin meta data QList("xcb")
qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: looking at "/usr/lib/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so"
qt.core.plugin.loader: Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "offscreen"
        ]
    },
    "archlevel": 0,
    "className": "QOffscreenIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 394496
}


qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: Got keys from plugin meta data QList("offscreen")
qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: looking at "/usr/lib/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so"
qt.core.plugin.loader: Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "linuxfb"
        ]
    },
    "archlevel": 0,
    "className": "QLinuxFbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 394496
}


qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: Got keys from plugin meta data QList("linuxfb")
qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: looking at "/usr/lib/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so"
qt.core.plugin.loader: Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimalegl"
        ]
    },
    "archlevel": 0,
    "className": "QMinimalEglIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 394496
}


qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: Got keys from plugin meta data QList("minimalegl")
qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: looking at "/usr/lib/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so"
qt.core.plugin.loader: Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimal"
        ]
    },
    "archlevel": 0,
    "className": "QMinimalIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 394496
}


qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: Got keys from plugin meta data QList("minimal")
qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: checking directory path "/opt/app2/platforms" ...
qt.core.library: "/usr/lib/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so" loaded library
qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: checking directory path "/usr/lib/plugins/egldeviceintegrations" ...
qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: looking at "/usr/lib/plugins/egldeviceintegrations/libqeglfs-emu-integration.so"
qt.core.plugin.loader: Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/plugins/egldeviceintegrations/libqeglfs-emu-integration.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.qt.qpa.egl.QEglFSDeviceIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.5",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "eglfs_emu"
        ]
    },
    "archlevel": 0,
    "className": "QEglFSEmulatorIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 394496
}


qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: Got keys from plugin meta data QList("eglfs_emu")
qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: looking at "/usr/lib/plugins/egldeviceintegrations/libqeglfs-x11-integration.so"
qt.core.plugin.loader: Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/plugins/egldeviceintegrations/libqeglfs-x11-integration.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.qt.qpa.egl.QEglFSDeviceIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.5",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "eglfs_x11"
        ]
    },
    "archlevel": 0,
    "className": "QEglFSX11IntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 394496
}


qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: Got keys from plugin meta data QList("eglfs_x11")
qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: checking directory path "/opt/app2/egldeviceintegrations" ...
qt.core.library: "/usr/lib/plugins/egldeviceintegrations/libqeglfs-emu-integration.so" loaded library
Could not initialize egl display
```

How to fix this eglfs error?

Comment: Is the package installed? `sudo apt install libxcb-cursor0`

Comment: It is not installed I guess. On my core-image-minimal yocto image, I can't just  call "sudo apt install". I should be able to add the library to my local.conf file of my yocto project. But I have no idea what package should I install to have libxcb-cursor0 on my RPi 3 yocto image.